# How can I make a switch in navigation drawer have functionality?

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I'm trying to make a navigation drawer switch which switches between a normal theme and a dark theme of an app, however I can't get the switch to work.

I already have a working switch on mainactivity but I can't get it to work in the navigation drawer.

This is the code to switch between light/dark mode.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()==AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.HROTheme);
        }
        else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        modeswitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()==AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            modeswitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        modeswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    recreate();
                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    recreate();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should [create a custom view for it](https://github.com/Zhuinden/flowless/blob/8dadd0027f38afdeeccd0f3907db4db776c5f5e8/flowless-mvp-example/src/main/res/layout/view_left_drawer.xml#L2), include it in your DrawerLayout and then [write the code-behind for it](https://github.com/Zhuinden/flowless/blob/8dadd0027f38afdeeccd0f3907db4db776c5f5e8/flowless-mvp-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/examplegithubclient/presentation/activity/main/leftdrawer/LeftDrawerView.java#L20-L46)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an item in values/attrs like this: `<attr name="bottomback" format="color" />`

Then define "bottomback" in styles for your both dark and light styles like this:

`<item name="bottomback">#000</item>`

That must be different in both styles.
 now you can set the backgroundTint of drawer as this: `android:backgroundTint="?attr/bottomback"`